# How to pass viewpager instance to Adapter using an Interface class

Tags: java, android, interface

I have a an activity that holds many fragments. In each fragment i have a :

RecyclerView

Button

I can move from fragment to another using viewpager.

I am getting data from server and passing them to the adapter to populate the recyclerview as below :

```
adapter = new BrandsAdapter(getContext(), postArray,btValider,viewPager);
```

where postArray is a list of Strings.

BrandsAdapter.class :

```
 public BrandsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Brand> filteredItems,Button btValider,ViewPager viewPager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filteredItems = filteredItems;
        this.btValider=btValider;
        this.viewPager=viewPager;

    }
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
btValider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 .....
                 // Get user selected brands and move to another fragment
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);

                }
            });
```

How can i create an Interface where i can add mybutton and viewpager instances so i don't pass them directly through BrandsAdapter because as we know from a memory point of view passing viewpager instance or other views through constructor can create cyclic dependencies and therefore memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create an Interface,

```
public interface BtValiderClickListener {
void btValiderClick(int positon);
}
```

2. Implement this interface
3. Pass the instance of the interface to the adapter,

   ```
   adapter = new BrandsAdapter(getContext(), postArray,btValider,this);
   ```
4. In the adapter,

   ```
   private BtValiderClickListener btValiderClickListener;
   ```
5. then in your adapter constructor,

   ```
   public BrandsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Brand> filteredItems,Button btValider,BtValiderClickListener btValiderClickListener) {
   this.context = context;
   this.filteredItems = filteredItems;
   this.btValider=btValider;
   this.btValiderClickListener=btValiderClickListener;
   }
   ```
6. In onBindViewHolder,

   ```
    btValider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               btValiderClickListener.btValiderClick(3)
           }
       });
   ```
7. Override your method where you implemented interface,

   ```
      @Override
      public void btValiderClick(int positon) {
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(positon);
      }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @hassan :)